# Python static gallery generator code thumbnails directory

Tags: python

I have code:

```
class Gallery():
def __init__(self, directory = '.'):
    self.imgnames = []
    self.directory = directory

def get_files(self):
    self.filenames = os.listdir(self.directory)
    logging.debug("Directory files: %s" % self.filenames)

def generate_thumbnails(self):
    counter = 0
    for name in self.filenames:
        logging.debug("Trying to open %s" % name)
        counter+= 1

        if name == "loading.gif":
            continue

        try:
            im = Image.open(name)
            self.imgnames.append(name)
            im.thumbnail( (300,300) )
            logging.debug("Saving thumb-%s" % name)
            im.save("thumb-%s" % name)
            sys.stdout.write("\r%f%%" % (counter*100.0/len(self.filenames)))
            sys.stdout.flush()
        except IOError:
            logging.debug("File %s cannot be parsed by PIL, ignoring" % name)

def integrate_bootstrap(self):
    logging.info("Generating index.html")
    head = open("./gallery_files/index.html.head", 'r').read()
    tail = open("./gallery_files/index.html.tail", 'r').read()
    final = open("index.html", 'w')
```

and i would like change image thumbnails directory to save to ./gallery_files/thumbs/

when i change im.save("thumb-%s" % name) to im.save("./gallery_files/thumbs/thumb-%s" % name) not working.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: What's the current save location?

Comment: I don't think it can get much much obvious what you have to change than naming the argument `directory`.

Comment: Explain "not working". It is clear that it is not doing what you want it to do – else you would not have to ask – but *what* is not working? How does this fail? Do you get an error? Wrong images?

Comment: Current save location is where script.py is same directory where all jpg files are and its generating in same folder only add thumbs to filename and make mess cause thumbs are in same folder where jpg are, thats why i prefer to create folder in main directory where main script is with thumbs name.

Not working means there is no error message only dont do nothing script is running but nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot comment to your question. Therfore I want to give you an answer:

What is the error?

Does the folder `./gallery_files/thumbs/` exist? If not, then it needs to be created before saving.